# Using wurfl to redirect phones to mobile version while iPad/Playbook and desktops get that version

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, redirect, wurfl

For those of you who use wurfl, I just wanted to check if my logic was correct. I have a page that has both a mobile and desktop version.

If I want phones like iPhones, etc to be redirected to the smaller mobile version while iPads, PlayBooks and desktops get the full size version, is this the correct logic on the full size page:

if ($requestingDevice->getCapability("is_wireless_device") == "true" && $requestingDevice->getCapability("is_tablet") == "false") {
//redirect to mobile version
}

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct. I recommend you don't use wurfl to switch from mobile to desktop version. It penalize the application performance. It is better to use a simple switcher based on a set of heuristics to switch from mobile to desktop, and then use wurfl only ont he mobile version to obtain the devices capabilities.

There are a lot of code useful to recognize if a user-agent is a mobile user-agent.

Comment: Yes, if all you want to do is detect if a browser is "mobile" and redirect them have a look at the script from http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for "can_assign_phone_number" which seem to properly filter out tablet and keep phone.